# How to sync Geth and testRPC private nodes locally?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, blockchain.info-api, geth

I have setup 2 nodes, 1 on testRPC and the other on geth(using cmd and mist).

How to sync both the nodes so that I can write a crowdfunding smartcontract for the accounts in both the private nodes to contribute?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, running a node on testrpc cannot be connected to by other bodes unless they have the same genisis file. Testrpc isn't meant to be connected to by other nodes, it is meant to be a standalone node.

It would be simpler, to just create two or more *private* nodes and have them sync. Moreover, to get then to sync you will need to use `admin.addPeers()`in the geth console, in order for a node to communicate with another node. The parameter to enter would be the enode id of the node you want to synch with.

There are tutorials explaining how to do this in more detail. [Link to github guide](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster)

Comment: Is it possible to connect by knowing RPC path and piping with IPC path?
                                                                                                                                                      Please explain how and where to get RPC path and also the method of piping required.

Comment: It should show up when you startup a node, on the first few lines. The RPC/IPC path will be shown, however you can change the paths in the arguments you use when starting up geth.